# Can data.table's fread accept connections?

Tags: r, data.table

I have an executable that I can call using the `system()` command. This executable will print some data which I can pipe into R using:

```
read.csv(pipe(command))
```

`fread` has amazing performance which I would like to take advantage of bringing the data in, but I cannot use `fread(pipe(command))`. The alternative is to use the executable and dump its output to a file first, then read it in using `fread`. Doing so requires writing intermediate data to disk, and also adds overhead by introducing that intermediate step. Is there a way to wrap or use `fread` with my executable?

Comment: As `?fread` documentation states, you can read data as an output of shell command directly: `input: a shell command that preprocesses the file (e.g. fread("grep blah filename"))` . Or, in your case, something like this: `fread(command)`. Will it work in your case?

Comment: Absolutely correct, this was a bad question

Answer (score 2):

fread can't take connections for now and the feature has been requested in 2015: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/561

Even though Maksim's comment would be valid, it would not work on a windows machine.  Which, in some cases can be troublesome.